# How to create a Tokenizing Control for UWP as known from Outlook when using To, Cc and Bcc

Tags: xaml, winrt-xaml, win-universal-app, tokenize

There is a great article about how to write a Tokenizing Control for WPF here: [Tokenizing control – convert text to tokens](http://blog.pixelingene.com/2010/10/tokenizing-control-convert-text-to-tokens/)

[image]

But how is this accomplished in an UWP App? The Windows 10 UWP Mail client does this just fine, so I know that it is possible. But how?

Tokenizing is super useful for To/CC/BCC input areas, as we know it from Outlook and lately from the Windows 10 UWP Mail client.

I suspect that RichTextBlock or maybe RichEditBox combined with AutoSuggestBox could be part of the answer, but in the WPF example above FlowDocument is used and FlowDocumet is not supported in UWP.

[image]

Comment: Hello, did you find any solution for UWP, I need this control and your given link has WPF code, which is not working in UWP. So if you have done this then plz share it.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't looked at their code. They likely have a text input control of their own, but you could achieve a fairly similar and possibly acceptable effect by putting `(Rich)TextBox` and "token" elements in a `WrapPanel`. You won't be able to easily select all text, but you could get clickable token elements.
Otherwise - you might have a bit of work figuring out completely hand-crafted input and rendering.

Comment: Thanks for the tip I'll hvae to look more into it. I guess you mean the `VariableSizedWrapGrid` given that the `WrapPanel` is a WPF Control not available in UWP? I had hoped that someone might have some example code. I'm sure it's feasible but I'm also beginning to get the sense that this particular task will be taking more time to do that first anticipated.

Comment: There's a WrapPanel in WinRT XAML Toolkit.

Comment: @JasperHedegaardBojsen, plz share the UWP code for Tokenizing, hope you will have done it.

Comment: I'm still working on it. I will share here eventually or w/ link to Github, but time have unfortunately been scarce the part weeks.

Comment: OK great. I'll b waiting anxiously.